# Can we use another else if condition after the first else if condition ends?

Tags: c++

I have been assigned a task where I have to calculate taxes on an imported mobile. It's divided in two parts where I have used else if condition on both of them separately. So what I want to ask is that after the first else if condition ends, will it go over to the second else if condition or ignore it?

Here's some code I've written:

```
if (priceindollars >= 1 && priceindollars < 61)
regulatoryduty = 250;    
else if (priceindollars >= 61 && priceindollars < 131)
regulatoryduty = ((differentcurrency* 10) / 100);
else
regulatoryduty = ((differentcurrency* 20) / 100);
```

FIRST PART ENDS HERE

START OF SECOND PART

```
if (differentcurrency >= 10000 && differentcurrency <= 40000)
mobilelevy = 1000;
else if (differentcurrency >= 10000 && differentcurrency <= 40000)
mobilelevy = 3000;
else
mobilelevy = 5000;
```

I have calculated the outputs of some inputs on paper manually but they're different to what my compiler is showing

Comment: Did you try what happens, when you add another `else if`? Or what is the point of the question? Spoiler: you can chain else if endlessly.

Comment: @churill yes I did. From what I've gathered, I think it adds the values assigned to mobilelevy whether they satisfy the condition/conditions or not to the total tax variable (haven't mentioned that here) regardless. I am just confused whether this all can be done in a single else if condition or not

Comment: You mean, you want to combine first and second part with else if? In a chained `else if` only _one_ branch is executed. But since those two parts seem to do different things, they probably should _both_ be executed? I'm not sure if I understand you correctly.

Comment: @churill Like, I want the result of the first condtion stored in a variable separately and the result of the second condition stored in another variable separately. But, I just want to know that after the first else if condition is run, it will go to the check second else if condition, yes? Sorry If I sound dumb but I just want to clear this thing

Comment: I think I know what you want now and try to formulate an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So first: `else if` can be chained endlessly. For the sake of simplicity let's take the following example:

```
if(a)
    doA();
else if(b)
    doB();
else if(c)
    doC();
else if(d)
    doD();
else
    doE();
```

Where `a`, `b`, `c` and `d` represent some boolean expression (could be for example `priceindollars >= 1 && priceindollars < 61` as in your code).

In this code *exactly one* `doX()` will be called.

- If a condition evaluates to `false` the else-branch is executed and the next condition is checked.
- If a condition evaluates to `true` the if-branch is executed and not further conditions are checked. (because they are located in the else-branch only)

The code is equivalent to the following:

```
if (a)
{
    doA();
}
else
{
    if (b)
    {
        doB();
    }
    else
    {
        if (c)
        {
            doC();
        }
        else
        {
            if (d)
            {
                doD();
            }
            else
            {
                doE();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

When written in the long form it's easier to see, why *exactly one* `doX()`is executed. So I guess, you have to keep the two blocks of your code seperately. If you combine them with `else if` *only one* varaible will be assigned a value.

I hope I understood your question correctly and this answers it.

Comment: thank you very much for a brief answer. I have got it I think. So if the whole block of an else if condition is checked and one condition has got true, be it the else one, then the code will come out of the condition and run from the very next line of the last check of condition i.e else, right?